# how to use a string that keeps a classifier

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

In my database, i have a table that occurs from following columns : Model_type, Train_score, Best_params.

- There are 3 unique values in model_type: LOGREG, RF, XGBOOST,
- the train_score column keeps the auc_score of each model for different parameters.
- best_params keeps the used parameters.

i get the best parameters for each model using below code

```
bests = worker_out.iloc[worker_out.groupby(['MODEL_TYPE'])['TRAIN_SCORE'].idxmax()][["MODEL_TYPE","BEST_PARAMS"]]
bests.set_index("MODEL_TYPE", inplace=True)

LOGREG = bests.loc["LOGREG"][0]
RF = bests.loc["RF"][0]
XGBOOST = bests.loc["XGBOOST"][0]
```

For instance, LOGREG keeps

```
print(LOGREG)
print(type(LOGREG))

LogisticRegression(C=0.01,class_weight='balanced',l1_ratio=0.2,max_iter=2000,penalty='elasticnet',solver='saga')
<class 'str'>
```

LOGREG is just a string right now, however i can use it as classifier. you can see what i want to do exactly in the below code.

```
LOGREG = LogisticRegression(C=0.01,class_weight='balanced',l1_ratio=0.2,max_iter=2000,penalty='elasticnet',solver='saga')
```

Comment: Do you store all the combinations of Models and parameters in the table? or just store the one that is better from that stored for each model?

Answer (score 0):

How about `LOGREG_model = eval(LOGREG)`.

I changed the name from `LOGREG` to `LOGREG_model`

Comment: String evaluation is not recommended if there are other, clearer ways to achieve the same

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov True. But other ways seemed to include some tiring parsing, and I was suggesting this as a quick solution for the op.

Comment: Quick solutions break sometime …

Answer (score 0):

Try dictionay, not pandas:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification()

rf = RandomForestClassifier()
lr = LogisticRegression()

models = {"rf": rf, "lr": lr}

for model in models:
    models[model].fit(X, y)
    
scores = {}

for model in models:
    scores[model] = models[model].score(X, y)
    
print(scores)
```

---

```
{'lr': 0.9, 'rf': 1.0}
```

Comment: @furkan Was it helpful? Did it answer your question? If so please consider accepting/upvoting